# Why is my constant variable being changed inside my function?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a function to implement a stochastic Hopfield network. The function takes as input a random pattern p, a weights matrix, and a beta value along with the original pattern (in the first iteration the random pattern and the original pattern would be the same.) The function is called recursively so that the output of each iteration is the input of the next iteration, however the original pattern should remain unchanged through all iterations. But, my original pattern changes along with my p(i) pattern which I don't understand why.

One strange thing that this is the case when the initial random pattern and the original pattern are even dissimilar at many indices. If the two are completely (at all indices) different then this would not be the case. However, some exceptions appear here as well which I will explain in the code. Below is the function that executes one update step for the network.

```
def stochastic_feed(input_pattern, weights, beta, original_pattern):

    bits = len(input_pattern)
    bias = 0
    new_stoch_pattern = input_pattern

    random_neuron = int(np.random.choice(range(bits), replace=True))
    for i4 in range(bits):
        bias += weights[random_neuron][i4] * input_pattern[i4]
    probability = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-2 * beta * bias))
```

This is the line where the problem occurs and the original pattern is changed to be the same as new_stoch_pattern which I don't understand why.

```
    np.put(new_stoch_pattern, random_neuron, np.random.choice([1, -1], p=[probability, 1-probability]))
```

And True is printed out by the console

```
    print(np.array_equal(new_stoch_pattern, original_pattern))

    return new_stoch_pattern
```

finally, this is how I iterate recursively through the function.
The pattern to be fed into the function has the shape (1,N). The weights matrix has the shape (N,N) which you can set to random uniform numbers for the sake of this question.

```
new_pattern = original_pattern
iter = 1
while iter1 < 10000:
    new_pattern = 
    stochastic_feed(new_pattern, weights, 0, original_pattern)
    all_first_sums.append(first_sum)
    iter1 += 1
```

Something that happens here is that, for example if I do this:

```
new_pattern = -original_pattern
```

then the console will display false. But if write:

```
new_pattern[:] = -original_pattern[:]
```

then the original pattern is again changed along with the new_pattern. The same applies if:

```
new_pattern[:50] = -original_pattern[:50]
```

for instance.

I expect the new_pattern to be different than the original pattern which actually is, but the original should remain unchanged whereas this is not the case.

Comment: Well, the problem is gone if the original_pattern (which is needed for another calculation) is not included as a function input. But, I still want to know why this problem is happening.

Comment: `new_stoch_pattern = input_pattern` doesn't make a copy of the array, the two variables both refer to the same array.